# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I've run rake db:migrate, schema.rb looks right, and when I run .tables in rails dbconsole I can see the table I'm looking for.  I did do a rollback previously, but I ended up running rake db:reset afterwards.  Any other ideas?

Rails 4, Ruby 1.9.3

schema.rb:

```
`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130501043644) do

  create_table "playlists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "songs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "artist"
    t.string   "soundcloud"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "songs_playlists", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "song_id"
    t.integer "playlist_id"
  end

end`
```

Trace from running rake db:seed --trace

```
    `Could not find table 'playlists_songs'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:509:in `table_structure'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:396:in `columns'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `default'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:118:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:67:in `yield'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:67:in `default'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:67:in `columns_hash'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:25:in `column_for'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:37:in `bind'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:73:in `block in add_constraints'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:44:in `each'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:44:in `each_with_index'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:44:in `add_constraints'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:19:in `scope'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:100:in `association_scope'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:84:in `scope'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:382:in `scope'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:37:in `initialize'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:78:in `new'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:37:in `reader'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `songs'
    /Users/paulruescher/Desktop/Dropbox/gtfomp/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `load_seed'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bundler/gems/rails-78db16d440c6/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'

Rails 3.2.12 rake db:seed --trace

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: playlists_songs: INSERT INTO "playlists_songs" ("song_id", "playlist_id") VALUES (5, 5)
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:246:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:63:in `exec_insert'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association.rb:29:in `insert_record'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in concat_records'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:344:in `add_to_target'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:495:in `block in concat_records'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in `each'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:493:in `concat_records'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:134:in `block in concat'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:149:in `block in transaction'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:134:in `concat'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:116:in `<<'
/Users/paulruescher/Desktop/Dropbox/fomp/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:333:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/paulruescher/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'`
```

Comment: Can you show full error trace?

Comment: updated to include rake db:seed --trace

Comment: Try to recreate database and run all migrations again, or load schema directly via `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: Tried
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate, rake db:reset rake db:migrate and nothing.  Same with rake db:schema:load

Comment: for what it's worth, I've read that multiple ActiveRecord gems tend to mess things up and I had the active_model_serializers gem for a bit.  I removed it from my Gemfile, ran bundle install.  Perhaps there's a way to completely remove it?

Comment: Try `gem unistall active_model_serializers `

Comment: that didn't work either...  might just start a new app from scratch at this point and see if I can get this to work first

Comment: I even just tried with an older version of Rails (3.2.12) and I'm getting a relatively similar error.  Updated original message with rake db:seed --trace

Comment: so I changed my table to "playlists_songs" and now playlist.songs works.  I just assumed since I wanted a belongs_to_has_many relationship that it would work both ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you schema, you have **songs_playlists** but in your model you are looking for **playlists_songs**

Comment: Lazarus is correct, by default Rails maps association table names in alphabetical order. And since 'p' goes before 's', the '**p**laylists_**s**ongs' is the table it's trying to find.