# Rspec and Rails for Zombies-Test not working

Tags: ruby, rspec, rails-for-zombies

Im going through the rspec rails for zombies lessons and i am having trouble running the tests in that they are not reading my ruby code in my App/models folder. I even tried to put the ruby file i call zombie.rb into the spec folder itself and require_relative and still the test are failing can someone please help me out. I am a newbie and I find that TDD is the best and fastest way to learn to code profeciently.My code is below, What I have in both the zombie_spec.rb file as well as the zombie.rb file respecively:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'
require_relative 'zombie'

describe Zombie do

  it 'is invalid without a name' do

    zombie = Zombie.new
    zombie.should_not be_valid

    end

   it 'include tweets' do

     tweet1 = Tweet.new(status: 'Uuuuunhhhhh')
     tweet2 = Tweet.new(status: 'Arrrrggggg')
     zombie = Zombie.new(name: 'Ash', tweets: [tweet1, tweet2])
     zombie.tweets.should include(tweet1)
     zombie.tweets.should include(tweet2)

     end

 end
```

and the zombie.rb file here

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :Tweet
validates :name, presence: true
end
```

This is the test result i'm getting

```
1) Zombie is invalid without a name
     Failure/Error: zombie = Zombie.new
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'zombies'
     # ./zombie_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>


2) Zombie include tweets
     Failure/Error: tweet1 = Tweet.new(status: 'Uuuuunhhhhh')
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Tweet
     # ./zombie_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your finding the `Zombie` model, because you're getting an error from `ActiveRecord` and it's complaining about the fact that it can't find the `zombies` table in your database, which suggests you haven't done your database migration yet (or had a problem with it).

The second error indicates that you haven't required any file that defines `Tweet`.

Comment: i did rake my database but the active record error still occurs.

Comment: Have you looked at your database to confirm that the table is present?

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313304/activerecordstatementinvalid-could-not-find-table and others, this is the error message you get when the database isn't set up right.